# How do implicitly declared (object level) member functions work according to the ISO C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

Are these class definitions equivalent?

First definition:

```
class A
{
    std::string s;
};
```

Second definition:

```
class A
{
    std::string s;
public:
    A() : s() {  }
    ~A(){  }
    A(const A& AA) : s(AA.s) {  }
    A(A&& a) noexcept : s(std::move(a.s)) {  }
    A& operator=(const A& AA){
        s=AA.s;
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(A&& a) noexcept{
        s=(std::move(a.s));
        return *this;
    }
    const A* operator&() const{ return this; }
    A* operator&(){ return this; }
};
```

If they are not, could you show me a class definition that is equivalent to the first one, and explicitly defines all member functions of class A?

Comment: They are certainly distinct; the second one initializes `s` differently in its default constructor.

Comment: @MadameElyse: I'm guessing it's just a typo on OP's part. Daniel, please clarify... Also,, "As" is a rather poor choice for a class name, it's quite confusing. Even for an MWE; use "A" instead.

Comment: `string("")` vs `string()` - one is not a default constructor

Comment: `operator&` is not implicitly declared.

Comment: @Barry: But the effect of it will be the same.

Comment: Not entirely the same: declaring one means you can write `A::operator&`.

Comment: `operator&` Never, ***EVER*** overload this.

Comment: @NicolBolas: "operator& may be overloaded for a pointer wrapper class to obtain a pointer to pointer" [ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof ] Somebody has broken your golden rule, and we pay for it by using template< class T > T* addressof(T& arg).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your definition of "**equivalent**".

- Assembly output of the code gen? **Yes**, for a good compiler and optimizer, they should be. :-)
- Compiler's assumptions while generating ASTs and making class representations or Intermediate code? **No**, why?

... from [C++14's standard draft n3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)(I believe it isn't so different from the main standard)..

To make things brief, Of the special member functions, taking a case of default constructor, we see from this section: *(emphasis are mine)*

> **12.1.5:** .... Before the defaulted default constructor for a class is implicitly defined, all the non-user-provided default constructors
>   for its base classes and its nonstatic data members shall have been
>   implicitly defined. *[ Note: An implicitly-declared default
>   constructor has an exception-specification. An explicitly-defaulted
>   definition **might** have an implicit exception specification, see 8.4.
>   —end note ]*

The above doesn't exactly apply to you code, nonetheless, further supporting evidence is somewhere in

> **12.6.3:** A non-explicit copy/move constructor is a converting constructor. *An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is **not** an explicit constructor; it may be called for implicit type conversions.*

*Check for your self, there are many more supporting evidences*... So, in the standard's sense, once you explicitly define any special member function, its different from what the compiler would have created and its associated assumptions.

But at the end of the day, the same code may be generated by the code generator. :-) . Just that the assumptions of the compiler during compilation may be different.

**TLDR;**

There are a lot of other paragraphs in the standard(draft) where it makes distinctions between the effects of implicitly defined special member functions and its converse(its mostly silent on that). You can pick the standard up and search for all occurrences of the phrase "implicitly-defined"

Comment: I don't see how from the first quote follows that a user-provided default constructor cannot be "equivalent" to the implicitly defined one (which was the OP's question). I do not fully understand the second quote, but cannot quite make the connection either.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, For the OP's use case, at code level, they are obviously going to be the same. It also depends on your definition of "equivalence". I am speaking in the broader sense that the compiler makes certain assumptions while creating class representations, some of these assumptions may not be made if the user explicitly declares and defines special member functions

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider ...I have modified my answer

Comment: I understand that you think the compiler makes assumptions, and that you think the standard makes different statements about implicit default, explicit default and user-provided special member functions. I just don't see how the first quote makes an assumption the user provided ctor doesn't fulfill. The detail about implicit vs. explicitly-defaulted definition is irrelevant because there are no explicitly-defaulted functions here. As long as the user-proivded functions are carefully declared and defined along the line of the implicit ones (e.g. wrt exception specs), I see no problem.

Comment: Plus, on an ontological note: What assumptions the compiler makes we don't know; the only hint we have is the produced code. If the code  is identical we can safely assume, for Occam's sake, that the underlying assumptions, moral values and cosmological musings of the compiler were identical as well.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, I get your point, I will revert on the first quote. Thanks

Comment: And perhaps be more specific in which way the second (or any other) quote leads to non-equivalence of the implicit and user-provided ctor. Best would be to provide a code snippet as proof that one can not model the behavior of an implicit (perhaps move/copy) ctor with a user-provided ctor. Are user-provided copy/move ctors always explicit constructors, while implicit ones are not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102849/discussion-between-whiztim-and-peter-a-schneider).